# Missing vertical space in tabulary

Tags: tabulary

Please consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabulary}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabulary}{5cm}{rL}   
    A & B\\[5cm]
    A & B\\
\end{tabulary}

\end{document}
```

Previously (with array.sty v2.4d) this resulted in an increased space between the two rows, but with array.sty v2.4h no space is inserted.

Is there any way to restore the previous behaviour?

Comment: You might have hoped that the authors of array package would communicate with the authors of tabulary... I'll see what I can do....

Answer (score 2):

> Based on the chat message https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46198018#46198018

You could use the following workaround:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabulary}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabulary}{5cm}{rL}   
    A & B\\ \noalign{\vspace{2cm}} 
    A & B\\
\end{tabulary}

\end{document}
```